# Bootstrap 4 to Bootstrap 5 migration, container issue

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, media-queries, bootstrap-5

Looking to migrate from Bootstrap 4 to Bootstrap 5. Container max-width seems to be different on default setting. Any idea why and what should be changed to look like Bootstrap 4? I am new to Bootstrap, please let me know what is the fastest way to start with it if the question is wrong.

Comment: Bootstrap 4’s [containers](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.6/layout/overview/#containers) go from extra-small to extra-large. Bootstrap 5’s [containers](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/layout/containers/#how-they-work) go from extra-small to XX-large, one more size, which was added to support the wider displays now in use. If you don’t want your content spread wider than a certain amount, add a max-width to your container.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since Bootstrap 5 added a **new XXL breakpoint** at `1400px`, the widest container breakpoint increased from `1140px` (Bootstrap 4) to `1320px` (Bootstrap 5).

Therefore, if you want the same container width behavior as Bootstrap 4, override the `.container` max-width CSS for the XXL breakpoint...

```
@media (min-width: 1400px) {
    .container {
        max-width: 1140px;
    }
}
```

[Responsive Demo](https://codeply.com/p/zqlVfz2Xfu)

Answer (score 0):

Bootstrap 5 includes six default breakpoints.

[image]

These breakpoints are customizable via Sass. You’ll find them in bootstrap's **_variables.scss** stylesheet.

```
$container-max-widths: (
  sm: 540px,
  md: 720px,
  lg: 960px,
  xl: 1140px,
  xxl: 1320px   // Use 1140px instead; 
);
```

---

If you don't use Sass, just rewrite `.container`'s max-width as `@Zim` mentioned.

```css
@media (min-width: 1400px) {
  .container {
    max-width: 1140px;
  }
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-+0n0xVW2eSR5OomGNYDnhzAbDsOXxcvSN1TPprVMTNDbiYZCxYbOOl7+AMvyTG2x" crossorigin="anonymous">


<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col bg-info p-5">
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Laudantium, ratione eum? Alias ipsa illum tempore, maxime cumque accusamus quos quidem culpa pariatur porro sit atque deleniti delectus consectetur praesentium. Eligendi?
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```